# iptables: Filtering in Prerouting chain

Tags: linux, iptables

Why it is not recommended to do any filtering in PREROUTING chain in nat and mangle tables?

Comment: Check this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243079/netfilter-iptables-why-not-using-the-raw-table

Comment: Thanks, Ibrahim!